# android app content firebase indexing

Tags: android, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

I want to show my app content in Mobile app of  Google Search whenever user search in google app.so that my app can shows in list with my app content..
in other words i am looking for [enable personal content firebase indexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/personal-content) ..

i went through lot of guides and docs, i am able to do app indexing for web urls..

but i also want to show my app contents in google search 
I tried to done this by using below code..

i created intent service

```
public class AppIndexingService extends IntentService {
    DatabaseAccess databaseAccess;


    public AppIndexingService() {
        super("AppIndexingService");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.shamukey));
        databaseAccess.open();
        ArrayList<Indexable> indexableNotes = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<RaviMessages>indexableMessagesArrayList=databaseAccess.readArticles("bagale");
        for (RaviMessages recipe :indexableMessagesArrayList ) {

            Indexable noteToIndex = Indexables.noteDigitalDocumentBuilder()
                .setName(recipe.getName())
                .setDescription(recipe.getStatus())
                  .setUrl("android-app://com.itsvibrant.FeelMyLoveMarathi/")
                .put("image","http://www.logospike.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Android_Logo_04.png")
                .build();

                indexableNotes.add(object);
            }


        if (indexableNotes.size() > 0) {
            Indexable[] notesArr = new Indexable[indexableNotes.size()];
            notesArr = indexableNotes.toArray(notesArr);

            // batch insert indexable notes into index
            FirebaseAppIndex.getInstance().update(notesArr);
        }

    }
}
```

Android manifest file.

```
<application
        android:name=".ApplicationContext"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/fml_mar"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value="com.itsvibrant.FeelMyLoveMarathi.MainActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />


            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="android-app"
                    android:host="com.itsvibrant.FeelMyLoveMarathi" />
                <data
                    android:host="ravindrabagale.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="shayari"
                    android:scheme="ravindrabagale" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <service android:name="AppIndexingService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.gms.permission.APPINDEXING">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.appindexing.UPDATE_INDEX" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


    </application>
```

But Still i am not able to show my app contents in google search.. what wrong i am doing ?? or am forgetting something??

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the correct property for your android app & website on https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools?

Also, have you verified your website via the Play Store's Developer portal? If not, here's a link to those instructions. For some reason these steps aren't really spelled out directly in the Firebase examples of App Indexing.